# Show all category with number of posts in that category next to the category

Tags: mysql

The problem I have is I am trying to display all the types and number of posts associated with that type in 1 query.

For example:

```
Streets 2
Avenues 3
Roads   7
```

I have 2 tables in my database, one is called type and the other is called posts, posts has type_id as a foreign key linking the two tables together.
Each post will have a type_id, this is basically a drop down select box where people can choose what type of post it is and when submitted the post gets categorized by type.

The database is on a live server running MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM type INNER JOIN posts ON  type.type_id = posts.type_id
```

I get all the linked rows with posts associated with type but I can't get the query to display the count next to each type

Comment: _GROUP BY_ - `SELECT type.name, COUNT(*) FROM type INNER JOIN posts ON  type.type_id = posts.type_id GROUP BY type.type_id, type.name`

Comment: That is amazing, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to aggregate the result:

```sql
SELECT   t.name, COUNT(*)
FROM     type t
JOIN     posts p ON t.type_id = p.type_id
GROUP BY t.name
```

Comment: Does it matter if the join is not an inner join?

Comment: @Justin `join` is a short hand for `inner join`. Some people like to be more explicit and state `inner join`, I personally prefer to type less.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` to aggregate the data and then count the groupings. Remember that the column you want to display (`SELECT`) must be in the `GROUP BY` clause.

If `type.name` **is unique** then you can solely rely on it in the grouping.

```
SELECT type.name, COUNT(*) 
FROM type type
JOIN posts post ON type.type_id = post.type_id 
GROUP BY type.name
;
```

If `type.name` **is not unique** then you must group by `type.type_id` too in order to get distinct groupings.

```
SELECT type.name, COUNT(*) 
FROM type type
JOIN posts post ON type.type_id = post.type_id 
GROUP BY type.type_id, type.name
;
```